# Divisors in a pair of planes intersecting in a line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi_1, \pi_2$ be two planes in $\mathbb{P}^3$ intersecting in a line $L$. Let us denote its union by $X$. 
I would like to understand better the Picard group of $X$.

I would also like to know what is the canonical divisor of $X$.
Is it a Cartier Divisor?

I have some conjectures about these questions, but I have not found a reference that allows me to prove or disprove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Picard group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ and is generated by $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(1)\vert_X$. The canonical class corresponds to the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-2)\vert_X$, it is a Cartier divisor.

Comment: Dear @Sasha, it seems that you are just restricting the generator of the Picard group of $\mathbb{P}^3$ to $X$ and using the adjunction formula. Are we allowed to do this when $X$ is singular (and moreover non-normal)? Do you know of a reference for this? Thank you.

Comment: The restriction of a line bundle is always a line bundle, this is evident.

Comment: OK, $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(1)|_X$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-2)|_X$ are line bundles in $X$. Why are them a generator of $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$ and the canonical line bundle of $X$ respectively? I only know references for the adjunction formula in the smooth case, and I am not sure of what result you are using for the other claim.

Comment: A line bundle on $X$ is determined by its restrictions to $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$, i.e., by a pair of line bundles $\mathcal{L}_1$, $\mathcal{L}_2$. Furthermore, the restrictions $\mathcal{L}_i\vert_L$ should be isomorphic, hence $\mathcal{L}_i \cong \mathcal{O}_{\pi_i}(k)$ for the same $k$, and this line bundle is the restriction of $\mathcal{O}(k)$ from $\mathbb{P}^3$. The answer to your question about the canonical class depends on the definition you use.

Comment: Dear Sasha, since the canonical sheaf of a plane $P$ is $\mathcal O_P (-3)$, I would have expected the canonical sheaf on $X$ to be $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(-3)\vert  X$.                                                       Am I missing something?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Dear Georges, why do you think so? Following this logic you could expect that the canonical sheaf of a triangle of lines on a plane is the restriction of $\mathcal{O}(-1)$, while in fact it is $\mathcal{O}$ (since such a triangle is a singular elliptic curve).

Comment: Dear Sasha, what you write is most certainly correct: I only stated what  "I would have expected" and I had no good reason for that expectation, except ignorance and naïvety!  If you have the time, would you be so kind as to add a few lines of explanation to your answer, in order to  to initiate me to the computation of the canonical class of a reducible variety ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: The canonical divisor class as the closure of the divisor of a top degree differential form on the smooth locus is not well-defined on non-normal varieties, but the dualizing line bundle is well defined as soon as the variety is Gorenstein. Any hypersurface (even reducible or non-reduced) in a projective space is Gorenstein and its dualizing line bundle is computed by the (usual) adjunction formula.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: I think you already asked this some time ago. Yes, I am.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations, Sasha. And apologies for my bad memory: I have deleted my  redundant personal question.